# Sh Script JSON values from JSON string

Tags: json, grep, sh

i have a file which contains an JSON object as a string:

```
{"STATUS":[{"STATUS":"S","When":1530779438,"Code":70,"Msg":"CGMiner stats","Description":"cgminer 4.9.0"}],"STATS":[{"CGMiner":"4.9.0","Miner":"9.0.0.5","CompileTime":"Sat May 26 20:42:30 CST 2018","Type":"Antminer Z9-Mini"},{"STATS":0,"ID":"ZCASH0","Elapsed":179818,"Calls":0,"Wait":0.000000,"Max":0.000000,"Min":99999999.000000,"GHS 5s":"16.39","GHS av":16.27,"miner_count":3,"frequency":"750","fan_num":1,"fan1":5760,"fan2":0,"fan3":0,"fan4":0,"fan5":0,"fan6":0,"temp_num":3,"temp1":41,"temp2":40,"temp3":43,"temp2_1":56,"temp2_2":53,"temp2_3":56,"temp_max":43,"Device Hardware%":0.0000,"no_matching_work":0,"chain_acn1":4,"chain_acn2":4,"chain_acn3":4,"chain_acs1":" oooo","chain_acs2":" oooo","chain_acs3":" oooo","chain_hw1":0,"chain_hw2":0,"chain_hw3":0,"chain_rate1":"5.18","chain_rate2":"5.34","chain_rate3":"5.87"}],"id":1}
```

now i want to get some values from keys in this object within a sh script.

The following cmd works, but however not for all keys!?

this works: (i get "750")

```
grep -o '"frequency": *"[^"]*"' LXstats.txt | grep -o '"[^"]*"$'
```

but this not: (empty)

```
grep -o '"fan_num": *"[^"]*"' LXstats.txt | grep -o '"[^"]*"$'
```

same with this:

```
grep -o '"fan1": *"[^"]*"' LXstats.txt | grep -o '"[^"]*"$'
```

Working on a xilinx OS, which has no python, so "jq" will not work and grep has no "-P" option. So anyone have an idea to work with that? :)

Thanks and best regards,
dave

Comment: frequency has double quoted value whereas fan_num and fan1 don't have quotes, just numbers...

Comment: You should be using `jq`, not `grep` or any other line-oriented tool. `jq '.STATS[].frequency'`, etc. `jq` is statically linked, so there are minimal dependencies for installing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to do more than just `g/re/p` you should be using awk, not combinations of greps+pipes, etc.

```
$ awk -v tag='frequency' 'match($0,"\""tag"\": *(\"[^\"]*|[0-9]+)") { val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); sub(/^"[^"]+": *"?/,"",val); print val }' file
750

$ awk -v tag='fan_num' 'match($0,"\""tag"\": *(\"[^\"]*|[0-9]+)") { val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); sub(/^"[^"]+": *"?/,"",val); print val }' file
1

$ awk -v tag='fan1' 'match($0,"\""tag"\": *(\"[^\"]*|[0-9]+)") { val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); sub(/^"[^"]+": *"?/,"",val); print val }' file
5760
```

The above will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box. If you have GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub() you can write it a bit briefer:

```
$ awk -v tag='frequency' 'match($0,"\""tag"\": *(\"[^\"]*|[0-9]+)",a) { print gensub(/^"/,"",1,a[1]) }' file
750
```